# adding pojos to sqlite in android (bulk insert) ArrayList<POJO>

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I am reading data from a text file and have to insert data to database, but the problem is that I am passing the `ArrayList<MidSemQuestions>` to insert method. 
How to get and insert data to sqlite in `addMidSemQuestion()` method

```
 public static void readQuestions(InputStream inputStream, Context context) {
    ArrayList<MidSemQuestions> midSemQuestionses=new ArrayList<MidSemQuestions>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] contents = line.split("-");

            MidSemQuestions midSemQuestions=new MidSemQuestions();
            midSemQuestions.setMarks_id(contents[0]);
            midSemQuestions.setQuestion_id(contents[1]);
            midSemQuestions.setSubject(contents[2]);
            midSemQuestions.setQuestion(contents[3]);
            midSemQuestionses.add(midSemQuestions);

            CDataSource cDataSource=CDataSource.getInstance(context);
            if(cDataSource.getMidSemQuestionCount()==0) {

  //how to insert the data to database

                cDataSource.addMidSemQuestions(midSemQuestionses));
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and for inserting data , here i want to bulk insert the data but i am not able to parse the arrayList

```
   public void addMidSemQuestions(MidSemQuestions midSemQuestions)
{
    openWritable();
    m_sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MARKS_ID, midSemQuestions.getMarks_id());
        values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, midSemQuestions.getSubject());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION_ID, midSemQuestions.getQuestion_id());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, midSemQuestions.getQuestion());
        // Notice how we haven't specified the primary key. SQLite auto increments the primary key column.
        m_sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE, null, values);
        m_sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        Log.d(LOG,"Database: "+values);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG,"Error while trying to add mid sem questions to database");
    }finally {
        m_sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

please help to modify the `addMidSemQuestion()` method.

Comment: can please share with me what is the error?